# Upload File to blob storage using rest API

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage

I'm trying to upload files to blob storage using the following method :

```
public static void UploadBlobWithRestAPISasPermissionOnBlobContainer(string blobContainerSasUri, string blobName, byte[] blobContent)
{
    int contentLength = blobContent.Length;
    string queryString = (new Uri(blobContainerSasUri)).Query;
    string blobContainerUri = blobContainerSasUri.Split('?')[0];
    string requestUri = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0}/{1}{2}", blobContainerUri, blobName, queryString);
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(requestUri);
    request.Method = "PUT";
    request.Headers.Add("x-ms-blob-type", "BlockBlob");
    request.ContentLength = contentLength;
    using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
    {
        requestStream.Write(blobContent, 0, contentLength);
    }
    using (HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
    {

    }
}
```

I'm getting the following error :

> "The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden."

I have the blob sasquery string and the full blob url  :

> https://domainname.blob.core.windows.net/myContainer/18/Picture.jpg
>
> ?sv=2015-04-05&sr=b&sig=Llp36ygMvUILVZfyaac%2Bx....

Can I just use the sas query and the url?

**Update** 
How I'm generating the SAS

var storageConnectionString = CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("MS_StorageConnectionString");

```
    var cloudStorageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(storageConnectionString);
    var cloudBlobClient = cloudStorageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

    var storageContainer = CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("MB_UserStorageContainer");

    var cloudBlobContainer = cloudBlobClient.GetContainerReference(storageContainer);

    var sasPolicy = new SharedAccessBlobPolicy()
    {
        SharedAccessStartTime = DateTime.UtcNow,
        SharedAccessExpiryTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(5),
        Permissions = SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Write,
    };

    var resourceName = $"{fileName}";

    var cloudBlob = cloudBlobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(resourceName);
    var sasQueryString = cloudBlob.GetSharedAccessSignature(sasPolicy);
   var blobUri = $"{cloudStorageAccount.BlobEndpoint}{containerName}/{fileName}";
```

Comment: You can upload file using SAS URL. In this case you're getting a WebException. Can you read the response stream of WebException's response. It should be an XML with more details about the error and should give you more idea about why your upload is failing with 403 error.

Comment: @GauravMantri `Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.` This is what the exception says

Comment: This generally means there's an issue with your SAS token. Can you please share your SAS token as well how you generate that token (share the code please if you generated it programmatically).

Comment: @GauravMantri Updated my question with the code you requested. Do you think it's related to the `SharedAccessStartTime`  and `SharedAccessExpiryTime`?

Comment: That's what I am also thinking. Can you try by removing `SharedAccessStartTime` (so that you avoid issues because of clock skewness) and increase `SharedAccessExpiryTime` to say 1 hour instead of 5 minutes?

Comment: @GauravMantri you are right. I was testing locally (the mobile app that sets the sasPolicy and the front end app that uploads the file using the sasquery returned by the mobileapp) and when I deployed on azure the problem is gone,
The issue is that the time on my machine isn't synchronized with the servers time I think (in the upload time).
Is it right?

Comment: That's correct. Azure Storage API allows some skewness in time (in my experience it has been 10-15 minutes) but if the clock on your computer is off by more than that the storage API calls will fail because of that.